# как задать слою X Y Z по умолчанию -10 по оси? (MapBox)

Tags: настройка, mapbox

как задать слою X Y Z по умолчанию -10 по оси?

условно у меня есть слой /layer/{x}{y}{z}.png мне нужно чтобы он рендерился как /layer/{x - 10}{y - 10}{z - 10}.png

подскажите есть ли такой функционал и вообще можно ли так сделать?